# Who/What is "Concerned Citizen" in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Novigrad I keep finding sheets of paper with messsages involving the "*Eternal Fire*" and Novigrad's church. They seem to be written by someone who is against Magic, Witches, Mages and anything involving the *Conjunction* (pretty much like the talk you usually skip when starting the game).

I remember I once found a corpse in a road and Geralt said: "*It wasn't Nathaniel. S••t*"

> Nathaniel is Vegelbud's murderer that Geralt managed to track down and kill. Along with the corpse, another of those messages.

All of them are signed by a certain "*- Concerned Citizen*" and are named "*Concerned Citizen Sermon*" when in the Inventory. Apparently, they are even resellable!

Now, who is this guy? Does he appear in the game or he's just a kind of Easter Egg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of the 'Carnal Sins' quest. The Reverend Nathaniel is not in fact the serial killer, when you find him if you just go ahead and kill him immediately you have acted to hastily and you can no longer find the real killer. When you do this you start to find these notes around Novigrad, they are telling you that the killer is still at large and you got the wrong person.

Comment: So I broke my game... Well, doesn't matter, that one too was a killer

Comment: @alex2003super Yes, I got this wrong the first time as well. The game makes Nathaniel so vile that you just want to cut him down as quickly as possible.

Comment: On my next playthrough I'll be more careful

Comment: @alex2003super No you didn't break your game. The Witcher 3 has A LOT of quests that can go many different ways - and it's all based on your choices! There is nothing game breaking about it though.

Comment: Yeah, I had to reload my save a couple o' times because of this.

Comment: I actually still find the Concerned Citizen notes sometimes even though I found the real killer. Not sure if it's left over from the quest, or if it's a bug, or what.

Comment: @PaulO. Yes, they do still seem to turn up, but Geralt doesn't make the comment about being wrong. My guess is they are just left overs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is indeed correct. I just wanted to add that the true killer is

> the coroner, Hubert Rejk.

He intentionally left the notes for Geralt, to lead him to Nathaniel.